# Filter monthly data based on 12 months and 4 countries in Python (Total 48 dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, filter

I have data of "onlineretail" consists of several columns (InvoiceNo, Description, Country, Month)

They are 4 countries and 12 months.

```
Country = ["France", "USA", "Mexico", "Brazil"]
Month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

I would like to create 48 dataframes based on 4 countries and 12 months (e.g., France Jan, France Feb,....,Brazil Nov, and Brazil Dec).
The pattern of dataframe that I need is shown below. How to write function to generate the 48 dataframe?

```
Data_France_Jan = onlineretail[(onlineretail.Country =="France") & (onlineretail.Month== "Jan")]\
.groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'Description'])['Quantity'].sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)\
.set_index('InvoiceNo')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby`:

```
data = dict(list(df.groupby(['Country', 'Month']))
```

`data` is now a dict indexed by 2 keys (Country, Month) => `data['France', 'Jan']`

You can also filter your dataframe before:

```
df = df[df['Country'].isin(Country) & df['Month'].isin(Month)]
data = dict(list(df.groupby(['Country', 'Month']))
```